# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError on Data Ingestion and Storage Pipeline

Tags: pyspark, optimization, out-of-memory, databricks, autoload

I have around 25GBs of data in my Azure storage. I am performing data ingestion using Autoloader in databricks. Below are the steps I am performing:

1. Setting the enableChangeDataFeed as true.
2. Reading the complete raw data using **readStream**.
3. Writing as delta table using **writeStream** to the azure blob storage.
4. Reading the change feed data of this delta table using **spark.read.format("delta").option("readChangeFeed", "true")...**
5. Performing operations on the change feed table using **withColumn** (Performing operations on **content** column as well, might be taking a lot of computation).

Now I am trying to save this computed pyspark dataframe to my catalog but getting the error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.
My databricks cluster has 1 Driver with 16GBs of memory and 4 nodes, max of 10 Workers with 16GBs of memory and 4 nodes each.

Is there a need to include more resources to the cluster or is there some way to optimize or replace the current pipeline?